# How can I check if Automatically Detect Settings is enabled in IE using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer

If the "LAN Settings" button on Internet Options is disabled through Group Policy, and you need to find out if "Automatically Detect Settings" is enabled, how can you do it (in PowerShell)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to disable this checkbox so you need to look at two different keys.

## DefaultConnectionSettings

This is a binary key with a lot of values in it; we want the 9th one (array index 8) and we want to check if the 4th bit is set.

We can do something like:

```
PS C:\> cd 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'
PS HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections> (gi .).GetValue("DefaultConnectionSett
ings")[8]
5
PS HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections>
```

We found that the value is 5. Since it's less than 8, the 4th bit is not set. If the value was greater than or equal to 8, this would signify that "Automatically Detect Settings" was checked.

## Autodetect

If present, `Autodetect` will change the "Automatically Detect Settings" checkbox on and off. You can get the value as follows:

```
PS C:\> cd 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings'
PS HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings> (gi .).GetValue("AutoDetect")
PS HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings>
```

Here the value was missing, which is quite normal and can be ignored. If it was present it should be 0 or 1 - 0 means "Automatically Detect Settings" was unchecked, and 1 means it's checked.